# Can I say the action noun in this usage

Tags: expressions, poetry, figurative-language

I want to say 'the city is destroyed into ashes' more poetically and uniquely. Can I say 'the city is with destruction into ashes'? More specifically, there's no city because of destruction and just the ashes are left.

Comment: _The city is with destruction_ is not a valid English sentence. _The city is destroyed_ or _The city is reduced to ashes_ would be the usual way to say it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Do you have an idea to express it in a more unique way? 'The city has destruction' may be also wrong...?

Comment: Yes, that is also wrong.

Comment: @Kate Bunting What about 'there is city destruction.

Comment: No. You can only speak of _the destruction of the city_ as something that has happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot say "destroyed into" at all. Nor can you say "the city is with destruction"

One could say "The city was destroyed. Nothing  but ashes remains." or "The city was burnt to ashes." or "where the city once stood only a heap of ash remains."

Comment: Could you give me some expression including linking verb 'be,' not auxiliaries?

Comment: @gggo "The once wonderful and boisterous city is now reduced to ashes".